# Error exists in the bytecode in maven deployment

Tags: java, maven, aem

I want to deploy my current project in aem. For this I am using command

```
    mvn clean install -PautoInstallPackage
```

But after Using this command I am Constantly getting the following error

```
hraj2@dluhraj263398 MINGW64 /d/Latest <REMOVED> (features/feature-phone)
$ mvn clean install -PautoInstallPackage
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] Platform AEM-Core
[INFO] <REMOVED> AEM Platform Foundation - Commerce
[INFO] <REMOVED> AEM Platform Foundation - Core
[INFO] <REMOVED> AEM Platform Foundation - UI apps
[INFO] <REMOVED> AEM Platform Foundation - UI apps
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Platform AEM-Core 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ parent ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0.1:enforce (enforce-maven) @ parent ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ parent ---
[INFO] Installing D:\Latest <REMOVED>\pom.xml to C:\Users\hraj2\.m2\repository\com\<REMOVED>\d2\aem\foundation\parent\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\parent-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building <REMOVED> AEM Platform Foundation - Commerce 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ commerce ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\Latest <REMOVED>\commerce\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0.1:enforce (enforce-maven) @ commerce ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ commerce ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Latest <REMOVED>\commerce\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) @ commerce ---
[INFO] Compiling 22 source files to D:\Latest <REMOVED>\commerce\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-scr-plugin:1.17.0:scr (generate-scr-scrdescriptor) @ commerce ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Platform AEM-Core .................................. SUCCESS [  0.302 s]
[INFO] <REMOVED> AEM Platform Foundation - Commerce ........ FAILURE [  1.607 s]
[INFO] <REMOVED> AEM Platform Foundation - Core ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] <REMOVED> AEM Platform Foundation - UI apps ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] <REMOVED> AEM Platform Foundation - UI apps ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.905 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-01-04T14:40:31+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/208M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.17.0:scr (generate-scr-scrdescriptor) on project commerce: Execution generate-scr-scrdescriptor of goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.17.0:scr failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.17.0:scr: java.lang.VerifyError: Constructor must call super() or this() before return
[ERROR] Exception Details:
[ERROR] Location:
[ERROR] com/adobe/cq/commerce/common/AbstractJcrCommerceServiceFactory.<init>()V @1: return
[ERROR] Reason:
[ERROR] Error exists in the bytecode
[ERROR] Bytecode:
[ERROR] 0x0000000: 2ab1
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.17.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/hraj2/.m2/repository/org/apache/felix/maven-scr-plugin/1.17.0/maven-scr-plugin-1.17.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/hraj2/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.5.11/slf4j-simple-1.5.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/hraj2/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.11/slf4j-api-1.5.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/hraj2/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.2/maven-archiver-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/hraj2/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/hraj2/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.0-alpha-7/plexus-archiver-1.0-alpha-7.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/hraj2/.m2/repository/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.scr.generator/1.10.0/org.apache.felix.scr.generator-1.10.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/hraj2/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-all/5.0.2/asm-all-5.0.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/hraj2/.m2/repository/org/osgi/org.osgi.core/4.2.0/org.osgi.core-4.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/hraj2/.m2/repository/org/osgi/org.osgi.compendium/4.2.0/org.osgi.compendium-4.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/hraj2/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-build-api/0.0.7/plexus-build-api-0.0.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/hraj2/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.8/plexus-utils-1.5.8.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>com.<REMOVED>.d2.aem.foundation:core:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :commerce

hraj2@dluhraj263398 MINGW64 /d/Latest <REMOVED> (features/feature-phone)
$
```

I am not able to rectify the error. I tried Reinstalling Maven, but that doesn't seems to help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which exact version of AEM are you using? Is it AEM 6.1 beta?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.If you got any solution,please share it with me.Any help will be appreciated.